# Number of quasi-particle in $|\psi_{BCS}\rangle$

Tags: superconductivity

What would the average number of quasi-particle in the superconducting state in BCS theory
$$\langle{\hat n}_k\rangle=\langle{\hat \gamma}_{k\sigma}^\dagger{\hat \gamma}_{k\sigma}\rangle$$
or 
$$\langle{\hat n}_k\rangle=\langle{\hat c}_{k\sigma}^\dagger{\hat c}_{k\sigma}\rangle$$
Or they are the same thing. Because we have changed fermionic basis after Bogoliubov transformation?

Comment: By “number of superconducting states” do you mean “number of quasiparticles in |BCS>”?

Comment: @ragnar Oh yes. I will correct my question.

Answer (score 0):

$\langle{\hat c}_{k\sigma}^\dagger{\hat c}_{k\sigma}\rangle$ will give you average number of quasi-partice. $\langle{\hat \gamma}_{k\sigma}^\dagger{\hat \gamma}_{k\sigma}\rangle$ will give you average number of Bogoliv particle. The calculation is straight forward.

\begin{align*}
\langle{\hat c}_{k\sigma}^\dagger{\hat c}_{k\sigma}\rangle&=|u_k|^2\langle{\hat \gamma}_{k\sigma}^\dagger{\hat \gamma}_{k\sigma}\rangle+|v_k|^2\langle{\hat \gamma}_{-k\bar\sigma}{\hat \gamma}_{-k\bar\sigma}^\dagger\rangle=2|u_k|^2f_k+2|v_k|^2(1-f_k)
\end{align*}
where $f_k=\langle{\hat \gamma}_{k\sigma}^\dagger{\hat \gamma}_{k\sigma}\rangle=\frac{1}{e^{\beta E_{k}}+1}$. As $\beta\to\infty$,
$$\langle{\hat c}_{k\sigma}^\dagger{\hat c}_{k\sigma}\rangle=2|v_k|^2$$
and
\begin{equation}\label{numberavg}\langle{\hat n}_k\rangle=1-\frac{\xi_k}{\sqrt{\xi_k^2+|\Delta_k|^2}}\end{equation}

Suggestions and changes to answer are welcomed.